# JSF mapping of ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-bean

I'm trying to access a Bean in my xhtml files by

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Recipe" action="#{recipeBean.newres}"/>
```

, which is working fine (the managedbean class name is also "RecipeBean"). 
Since I decided to do my project in german language, I wanted to change the name to "RezeptBean", which ended up in refactoring the Java-Class to "RezeptBean" and me adjusting in the xhtml to

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Recipe" action="#{rezeptBean.newres}"/>
```

I am really confused, since now the click on the button ends up in "Target unreacheable, identifier resolved to null", whereas the use of "recipeBean.newres" is still working. 
I think there might be a mapping of the managedbean names to their xhtml-pendant. Does anyone have a clue for me?

Btw, this is the Managedbean-Class:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class RezeptBean {
    private Recipe recipe;

    public RezeptBean(){
        recipe = new Recipe();
    }

    public String review(){
        return("recipe");
    }
...
```

Comment: Do you have beans.xml or faces-config.xml in your project?

Comment: Did you try Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: Tried already Clean and Rebuild. I got the following files:
faces-config.xml which is empty and I don't have a beans.xml

Comment: Did you try restart the container?

Answer (score 1):

> Since I decided to do my project in german language, I wanted to
>   change the name to "RezeptBean", which ended up in refactoring the
>   Java-Class to "RezeptBean" and me adjusting in the xhtml to

Why change the Bean name and refactor the code again.?

You can use the `name` attribute on `@ManagedBean`*[[link]](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html)* annotation.

That way you can keep the BeanName solid and change the Exposed ManagedBean name any time you require.

Example:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="rezeptBean")
public class RecipeBean{
....
....
}
```